# Loading dependencies from the most recent Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I have a simple console application targeting .netcoreapp3.1 and having FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.

On my machine, I have ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.3 installed.

Output from `dotnet --info`:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

When referencing a package in version `3.1.0` whose .dll is part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, this .dll is not outputted when the project is build - for example when referencing package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, its .dll is not in the build folder. During runtime, the actual file loaded comes from the path where Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 is installed (mentioned above).

When referencing the same package in version `3.1.3`, it's .dll is outputted to build folder. When I delete this .dll and run the application, it fails with the following error:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (TestReferences.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions', version: '3.1.3'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'
```

Why the package referenced by version `3.1.0` is loaded from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3` but when referencing by version `3.1.3` it is not found?

How to force .NET to use the .dll in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3`?

Comment: You said you have the runtime installed, do you have the sdk installed?

Comment: Yes, .NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]